# Call a Yii RESTFul API via http from another application

Tags: php, http, rest, yii

I have a Yii application with CRUD already done on a user table that i creaed. So i already have a view, model and controller. Now i want to create an RESTFul API with JSON format that another application can call to create a user. So far, i have the following code in my controller that works when i test it locally using an http request. As you can see in my code, the $post array has hard coded input data (just for testing purposes) and it works when i call the REST API in the browser using an http request as follows:

```
http://localhost/PregnancyApp/index.php/User/insert?
```

The /User is the controller class, and the /insert is the action function inside the controller shown below:

```
//Here is the code that i have in my controller class
public function actionInsert(){
$post = array('email'=>'Ethel@example.com',
'password'=>'ethelpass',
'nickname'=>'Ethel',
'is_paid'=>'0',
'due_date'=>'2014-01-01',
'ios_token'=>'0011110000',
'serial_num'=>'1100001111',
'picture'=>'null'
);


$command = Yii::app()->db->createCommand('INSERT INTO user (email, password, 
nickname,is_paid, due_date,ios_token, serial_num, picture )
VALUES (:email, :password, :nickname, :is_paid, :due_date, :ios_token, :serial_num, 
:picture)');

$command->bindParam(':email', $post['email']);
$command->bindParam(':password', md5($post['password']));
$command->bindParam(':nickname', $post['nickname']);
$command->bindParam(':is_paid', $post['is_paid']);
$command->bindParam(':due_date', $post['due_date']);
$command->bindParam(':ios_token', $post['ios_token']);
$command->bindParam(':serial_num', $post['serial_num']);
$command->bindParam(':picture', $post['picture']);
json_encode($command->execute());

echo "Please, check your database if the entry registered";
}
```

So my question is, how can i assign these values to the http post request to replace the hard coded $post array? I want the input values (in the array) to come from the client application.So how can i format the http post request that the client application can send to request my API to create a user?

Answer (score 0):

you can get the make the requester to send the variables in GET or POST format, and then you can get it like:

if it's a post:

```
$post = array(
    'email' => $_POST['email'],
    'password' => $_POST['password'],
    'nickname'=> $_POST['nickname'],
    'is_paid'=>'0',
    'due_date'=>date('Y-m-d'),
    'ios_token'=> $_POST['ios_token'],
    'serial_num'=> $_POST['serial_num'],
    'picture'=>null
);
```

or GET

```
$post = array(
    'email' => $_GET['email'],
```

and then echo the result

```
echo CJSON::encode(array('result'=>'success'));
```

but don't forget to clean the variable before using them